# SQL Select/Group by a list of column names

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

is there a way to do such thing?

suppose that i have the following table called columnstogroupby

```
ColumnsToGroupBy
Column1
Column2 
Coulmn3
```

and i have this query

```
Select sum(someColumn) Total,Column1,Column2,Column3 From MyTable Group By Column1,Column2,Column3
```

is there a way the i can create this query dynamically using the columnstogroupby table?
note that the `sum(someColumn) Total` is always the same, i just need to include all columns in the columnstogroupby in my select and group by clauses, is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible using dynamic SQL.

See the MSDN help page for [`sp_executesql`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) and be sure to consider the [security implications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669091.aspx).

A Google search for [`SQL Server dynamic`](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=sql%20server%20dynamic) returns plenty of examples too.